# How can I substitute @PrePersist in Spring data r2dbc

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc` (version 1.1.3) module in Spring Webflux application.
I want to add entity lifecycle callbacks to my persistence layer.
With Spring Data JPA it was possible with annotations like `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate`, etc.
Is there any convenient way to achieve this with Spring Data r2dbc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from the `spring-data-r2dbc:1.2.0` which is a part of the new [Spring Data 2020.0 release](https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/18/spring-data-2020-0-new-and-noteworthy-in-spring-data-r2dbc-1-2) it is possible with the new "Lifecycle Entity Callback API".

Here is a short example:

```
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.mapping.event.BeforeSaveCallback;


@Component
public class DefaultingEntityCallback implements BeforeSaveCallback<MyEntity> {

    @Override
    public Publisher<MyEntity> onBeforeSave(final MyEntity entity,
                                            final OutboundRow row,
                                            final SqlIdentifier table) {
        // do something
        return Mono.just(entity);
    }
}
```

Here is some documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#r2dbc.entity-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc)

> Spring Data R2DBC aims at being conceptually easy. In order to achieve
> this it does NOT offer caching, lazy loading, write behind or many
> other features of ORM frameworks. This makes Spring Data R2DBC a
> simple, limited, opinionated object mapper.

So you'll have to either write your own such mechanisms or write persistence code that doesn't depend on them.

Comment: I am not sure this high-level description rejects the existence of `@PrePersist`-like feature. I have found the following PR for supporting it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/pull/397. Unfortunately, it has not been  released yet in the main `spring-data-r2dbc` module